# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu - Can't load Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a newcomer to Ubuntu, and have just installed version 15.10 (64 bit) alongside Windows 10.  All seems to have gone well, but I can't boot Ubuntu from Grub.  I've checked the install from a live USB, and all appears ok (to my novice eyes).  Do I have to configure Grub in anyway, or have I inadvertantly installed the boot loader on an incorrrect partition?  I would be grateful for any advice, and apologise if this topic has already been covered previously.

Comment: Is Windows 10 originally on system or update from Windows 8 and then UEFI, or update from Windows 7 and probably BIOS boot? Did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows UEFI or BIOS? What brand/model system. Some require special settings.  But may be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

try boot repair

- either from an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)
- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Using Boot-Repair
Recommended repair

1. launch Boot-Repair from either :

   - the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
   - or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
2. Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
3. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Warning: the default settings are the ones used by the "Recommended Repair". Changing them may worsen your problem. Don't modify them before creating a BootInfo URL, and asking for advice on Ubuntu Forums Absolute Beginners Section or in Installation and Upgrades.

more info here [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably cause the windows bootloader loads first and doesn't let grub to load.

So try this. It should work. After you power-on the system press `esc` (or whatever key based on you computer) to pause startup and go to the boot options or BIOS (for non-UEFI systems).

There you will find the "Startup Menu". In this menu press the appropriate function key to select the " boot device option".

Selecting this will take you to a menu where you will see all the available boot devices. Some of the options will be :-

- OS boot manager
- Boot from EFI file
- Notebook Hard drive
- network adapter

Now if you have installed correctly then there should be  another option called `ubuntu...blah blah blah...`

Select that and grub should load properly.